# How can I do this in one MySQL Select query, I want to lose the foreach loop and the second select query?

Tags: php, mysql

The code below gives me the result I want, but it involves 2 Database queries. I would prefer to do it more efficiently with one database query. Is there a way I can structure the SELECT statement to give me the desired result below with one database query?

**DB table: rates**

**Rates  structure: id, seasonID, propID, rate**

```
try {

      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(seasonID), season.seasonDesc FROM `rates`
                        INNER JOIN season
                        ON rates.seasonID = season.id
                        WHERE propID = :propID";

      $sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql);

      $ar_val = array(':propID'=>$propID);

      if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
          while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

            $seasonID[$row->seasonDesc] = $row->seasonID;
            //print_r($seasonID);

           }

         }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    foreach($seasonID AS $key => $value){
        echo "<b>".$key."</b>";
    echo "<ul>";


                try {

                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
                    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `rates`
                                WHERE seasonID = :seasonID
                                AND propID = 1
                                ORDER BY AccomType,rateType";

                    $sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql); 

                    $ar_val = array(':seasonID'=>$value);

                    if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
                        while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                            echo "<li>".$row->accomType."<br>";
                            echo " ".$row->rateType." - ";
                            echo " R".number_format($row->rate,'2','.',' ')." ".$row->rateUnit."</li>";


                        }
                    }

                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
```

**Without the foreach loop I get the following result:**

```
    Season 1 Property 1 rate: 1
    Season 1 Property 2: rate 1
    Season 1 Property 3: rate 1
    Season 2 Property 1 rate: 1
    Season 2 Property 2: rate 1
    Season 2 Property 3: rate 1
    Season 3 Property 1 rate: 1
    Season 3 Property 2: rate 1
    Season 3 Property 3: rate 1
```

**Desired result (foreach loop gives me this result):**

```
Season 1
    Property 1 rate: 1
    Property 2: rate 1
    Property 3: rate 1

Season 2
    Property 1 rate: 1
    Property 2: rate 1
    Property 3: rate 1

Season 3
    Property 1 rate: 1
    Property 2: rate 1
    Property 3: rate 1
```

Comment: where are your codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Do not ask call query in loop - its extremly ineficient. You can easily download all data with just one query:

```
$sql = "SELECT rates.*, season. seasonDesc FROM `rates`
       JOIN seasons ON rates.seasonID = season.id
       WHERE -- insert here proper where case
       ORDER BY AccomType,rateType"
```

Now you need just a little trick while looping throught results:

```
$activeSeasonId = null;
while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
   if($activeSeasonId != $row->seasonID) {
        if(activeSeasonId != null) {
            //close previous <ul> here
        }
        // open new <ul> here

        $activeSeasonId = $row->seasonID;
   }
   // print your <li> here
}
//after everything close last <ul>
```

Trick is to save actual seasonID and check when it changes. Then what you have to do is just print new seasonDesc and keep looping.

Comment: I cannot do a join as this is all from one table

Comment: `season.seasonDesc` is from another table, right?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct ignore my comment.

Comment: I see what you are saying nice and simple, will try it out now.

Comment: OK it works great, one problem: I have a hanging </ul> at the start.

Comment: if($activeSeasonId != $row->seasonID) {
                                    
                                    if(activeSeasonId != null) {
                                        echo "</ul>\n\n";
                                    }
                                        
                                    echo "<ul>\n";
                                    $activeSeasonId = $row->seasonID;
                                        
                                }

Comment: So in the first iteration / loop the $activeSeasonId changes from null to the first $row->seasonID and prints out a closing </ul> | How do I fix that?

Comment: Make sure you checking this if statement first, and setting activeSeasonId later. Btw in your code there is missing `$` before variable: `if(activeSeasonId != null`

Comment: Adding the missing $ did the trick. Thanks for your solution, MUCH easier, simpler than my foreach longhand!

Comment: I'm glad it helps you :) And at the end just one last advice. Try to establish connection to database just once. Its expensive operation and you can get some strange errors in future (like max number of db connections exceeded). Much better idea is to use same connection in every place of your app.